# How to upgrade android studio without losing my SDK

Tags: android, android-studio

Basically, my current ver of android studio is 1.4.1. Now i want to upgrade it to 2.0, but while click on check for update it shows "download" option not "update and install"(which is basically a patch). 
please tell me the steps so that i can update it from zip without losing my SDK since it's a marshmallow + android N preview and i can't lose at all.

Comment: Why don't you copy the sdk to another place just in case it deleted the old data?

Comment: it should not touch the SDK folder

Comment: will you please explain the steps in a bit detail, not too much.Coz i don't want my studio gets corrupted

Comment: there should be no problem if you update to new version via downloading and in new version you can pass sdk location that you had earlier

Comment: but i have to uninstall the current version in  order to install a newer one and during the process my sdk will also uninstall. This is my concern.How can i come over this?

Comment: I was in your same situation and I clicked on the download button. It opened chrome and brought me to the Android Studio 2.0 changelog page. I closed the browser and tried again to click check for updates and there was the option to update it. Maybe it can work for your case too...

Answer (score 2):

I understand your condition because I faced the same issue there are two options

1) Add your `SDK` folder to `.RAR` archive and download android studio without `SDK` and install and then add the `SDK` manually after extracting it. This will work flawless.

2) keep restarting Android Studio and then check for updates and in few tries it will give you the option to download the patch of few `MBs`.

I used 2nd options for updating to version 2.0 and 1st option when I updated OS of my system.

Hope it helps

Comment: did you mean SDK folder which is in App data folder?

Comment: yup, is there a problem?

Comment: ok here is the procedure :
first add my SDK folder to zip 
and then uninstall the current ver.
and then install a new one
is that what you said ?
I'm too nervous to do this , that's why i'm confirming
because if anything goes wrong i cant put my laptop again to update the SDK for 2 days 
I hope you can understand my situation

Comment: Done but in other way....
i downloaded the zip file copied and pasted the file and  hide the already installed file.
By the Way thanks for suggestion. :)